# Loggin session not working in another page

Tags: php, session, pdo

I have a page name `authentication.php` once licked login it will show the session information in the same page, but when i try to display the same logged user information in another page like `userprofile.php` it won't show anything

```
<?php

    if ($_POST) {

      $logdb = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=mydbname', 'root', '12345');
      $logdb->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
      $stmt = $logdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username=:username AND password=:password");
      $stmt->bindParam(":username", $_POST['username']);
      $stmt->bindParam(":password", $_POST['password']);
      $stmt->execute();

    $atributes = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    if ($atributes) {
        session_start();

         //$_SESSION["loggedIn"] = true;
         $_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['username'];
         $_SESSION["ID"] = $atributes->ID;
         $_SESSION["country"] = $atributes->country;


      } else {
          echo 'Login failed!';
        }
      } else {
          echo '<form name="login" action="" method="POST">
      Username: <br />
      <input type="text" name="username"/><br />
      Password: <br />
      <input type="password" name="password"/><br />
      <button type="submit">Login</button>
      <a href="register.php">Register</a></form>';
      }

?>

<?php 
 echo  ($_SESSION["ID"]);
 echo  ($_SESSION["username"]);
 echo $atributes->country;
 ?>
```

Here is what i use in a new page to display logged user information but am not getting any result and also no error please can you assist me on that?

```
<?php 
session_start();

    if(!isset($_SESSION['username'])) {

         $_SESSION["ID"] = $atributes->ID;
         $_SESSION["username"] = $atributes->username;
         $_SESSION["country"] = $atributes->country;

} ?>
    <?php 
     echo  ($_SESSION["ID"]);
     echo  ($_SESSION["username"]);
     echo $atributes->country;
     ?>
```

Also at the header of my page i have a navbar like this

```
<?php if(!isset($_SESSION['username'])) { 
 include($root . 'includings/unloggedU.php');
}else{
include($root . 'includings/loggedU.php');
} ?>
```

Comment: yes , true , anyway he should get an error as there is no $attributes  in that page

Comment: It worked bu i have something like this `<?php if(!isset($_SESSION['username'])) { 
 include($root . 'includings/HunloggedU.php');?>
}else{
include($root . 'includings/HloggedU.php');
} ?>` for to nav bar loggedin and unlogged users

Comment: @Codesoft - but do you have access to your session vars now? As per Ryan Vincent's comment and mine above, always best to set the `session_start();` at the very top of the page - on all pages - before anything else at all after your `<?php` tag. You should only need to define them once to have access to theme globally.

Answer (score 0):

On the first page set `$_SESSION['country'] = $atributes->country;` as there is currently no session variable set for that in your code.

And on the second page you should have access to all of the session variables - which you can test individually to see if they are set if you want to.

```
  <?php 
  session_start();  // always put this at the top of the page see Ryan's comments

  echo $_SESSION["ID"] . "<br />";
  echo $_SESSION["username"] . "<br />";
  echo $_SESSION["country"] . "<br />";
  ?>
```

Comment: Is working bro but i have something like this `<?php if(!isset($_SESSION['username'])) { 
 include($root . 'includings/HunloggedU.php');
}else{
include($root . 'includings/HloggedU.php');
} ?>` for to nav bar loggedin and unlogged users